Cannot use ES6 import of Emscripten-generated JS file in Node environment
I have a web app that uses WebAssembly code to perform resource-intensive calculations. The C++ code is compiled with Emscripten with following flags:
--bind -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s EXPORT_ES6 --emit-tsd EmscriptenGeneratedModule.d.ts

This gives me a WASM binary file, type definitions and JS "glue" code that basically loads the binary code and contains a ES6 default export.
The import (import MainModuleFactory from './EmscriptenGeneratedModule' )works in browser environment. However, whenever I try to run my tests (yarn test) I get the following error in files that depend on the JS glue
Details:

    /XXX/EmscriptenGeneratedModule.js:3
      var _scriptName = import.meta.url;
                               ^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

Here's the useful part of package.json (stripped from dependencies, versions etc)
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "test": "jest",
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/jest.setup.ts"
    ]
  }
}

and jest.setup.ts
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import 'jest-canvas-mock'

Do you possibly know what is the issue with my environment? I usually use import statements in tests without any issues (these are from TS files, though). I think the issue might be with an explicit call to import.meta in the JavaScript code, but I don't have any control over that. I can only hope to fix the testing environment to support it
I already have set my project as a module by setting "type":"module" property in the package.json
I tried setting babel for parsing js files separately in jest settings (babel-jest)
I tried adding the experimental-vm-modules flag to jest runner, but it resulted with Must use import to load ES Module: /XXX/EmscriptenGeneratedModule.js
I managed to make it work in node when I ditched the EXPORT_ES6 flag from Emscripten compile options. But it broke the web and demanded some workarounds for node to work as well.
I compiled the C++ to CommonJs instead of ESM and retrieved the default export by
import * as ModuleExports from "./EmscriptenGeneratedModule.js"
const Module = ModuleExports.default

This allowed me to call Module() and use it in jest, but Module was always undefined in the web thus breaking it

Alright, I solved the issue (although I still don't know why jest did not want to work out of the box with that - apparently Jest already supports ES6 imports natively).
The main problem (as stated in original question) was the explicit call to import.meta.url in the Emscripten-generated glue code. To solve it, I needed to transpile the JS glue with babel-jest and add a babel-plugin-transform-import-meta plugin to replace import.meta with an alternative (more info in plugin documentation). It needs to be used with the ES6 property.
The modified package.json looks like this
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "test": "jest"
   },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/jest.setup.ts"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta",
        {
          "module": "ES6"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}

